# Will these jquery selectors all do the same thing?

Tags: jquery

Will these jquery selectors all do the same thing?
Is there any recommended order for the selector

```
$gender = $('input:radio.gender');
$gender = $('input:radio .gender');
$gender = $('input.gender:radio');
```

Comment: I think #2 would select the children of input:radio with the class="gender" as opposed to selecting an input.gender:radio element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

The first one will select an `input[type=radio]` with class `gender`.

The second is looking for an `input[type=radio]` which has an descendant which is not possible so nothing happens.

The third looking for an `input` with class `gender` which is `radio` but the syntax is invalid since `:radio` is equivalent to `[type=radio]` and looking for the attribute of the element. So the syntax is `input[type=radio]` or `input:radio` just like the first case.

Examples:
http://jsbin.com/dowiyunake/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Love the example, I always have so much trouble telling what my selectors have actually selected, when i am debugging. That is such a simple way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

First and third are the same (radio input with class "gender") while second selector will seek for an element with class gender inside radio input

Comment: I downvoted, as per @Sotiris example 1 and 3 are not the same.